# Recyclerview does not load first time activity is created

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit

I am adding items to my recycler list from an ADD activity which opens by clicking a button in the recyclerview activity. but when I add and close the ADD activity, the item does not show in the recyclerview activity unless I close it and open it again.

I get an ID if the add network call is successful. I then add ID to sqlite,finish the ADD activity and return to my recyclerview activity.I get the ID from sqlite and pass it to network call function to get my item.

This is my Recyclerview activity

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_subscriptions);

    db = SubscriptionDB.getInstance(this);
    sessionDBHelper = new SessionDBHelper(this);
    idDB = IDsDB.getInstance(this);


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.floatAddSub);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Subscriptions.this, AddSubscription.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    customerID = idDB.getCustomerID();

    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
    recyclerview = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.subscription_recycler);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerview.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerview.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    fetchInfo(customerID);
    if (subArrayList.size() > 0) {
        adapter = new SubRVAdapter(subArrayList, this, this.getSupportFragmentManager());
        subArrayList = db.getAll();
        recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
}

public void fetchInfo(String customerID) {
    apiInterface = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(APIInterface.class);

    Call<ArrayList<SubObject>> call = apiInterface.getSubscription(customerID);

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<SubObject>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<SubObject>> call, Response<ArrayList<SubObject>> response) {
            adapter = new SubRVAdapter(subArrayList, getApplicationContext(), getSupportFragmentManager());
            subArrayList = response.body();
            recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            int statusCode = response.code();
            Log.d("onresponse", "" + statusCode);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<SubObject>> call, Throwable t) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Log.d("onfailure", " " + t.getMessage());

            Toast.makeText(Subscriptions.this, "There is a network issue. Try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });
}



@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d("onResume", "RESUME");

    fetchInfo(customerID);
    if (subArrayList.size() > 0) {
        adapter = new SubRVAdapter(subArrayList, this, this.getSupportFragmentManager());
        subArrayList = db.getAll();
        recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

}
```

The ADD activity

```
 APIInterface apiInterface = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(APIInterface.class);
                    AddSubscriptionModel addSubscriptionModel = new AddSubscriptionModel();
                    addSubscriptionModel.setStickerNumber(stickerNumber);
                    addSubscriptionModel.setPin(Pin);
                    addSubscriptionModel.setUsername(username);
                    addSubscriptionModel.setPassword(password);
                    addSubscriptionModel.setEmail(phone);

                    Call<ArrayList<SubModel>> activate = apiInterface.addSubscription(addSubscriptionModel);
                    activate.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<SubModel>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<SubModel>> call, Response<ArrayList<SubModel>> response) {

                            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                int statusCode = response.code();

                                subsscriptions = response.body();

                                    String cusID = subsscriptions.get(0).getCustomer_id();
                                    String subID = subsscriptions.get(0).getSubscription_id();

                                    idDB.addCustomerID(cusID, subID);


                                }

                                Toast.makeText(AddSubscription.this, "SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                Log.d("onresponse", "" + statusCode);
                            }
                        }



                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<SubModel>> call, Throwable t) {

                            Toast.makeText(AddSubscription.this, "Network issues", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Log.d("onfailure"," " +  t . getMessage());


                        }
                    });

            finish();
        }
    });
```

[link to logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGnLg.jpg)

Comment: So, your fetchInfo method is not working as expected after network call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start activity with result like this

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Subscriptions.this, AddSubscription.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent,1);
    }
});
```

You will get result when you finish ADD activity

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    customerID = idDB.getCustomerID();
    fetchInfo(customerID);
    if (subArrayList.size() > 0) {
        adapter = new SubRVAdapter(subArrayList, this, this.getSupportFragmentManager());
        subArrayList = db.getAll();
        recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

and also you have to wait until you get API response, after you can finish ADD activity

```
Call<ArrayList<SubModel>> activate = apiInterface.addSubscription(addSubscriptionModel);
activate.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<SubModel>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<SubModel>> call, Response<ArrayList<SubModel>> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            int statusCode = response.code();
            subsscriptions = response.body();
            String cusID = subsscriptions.get(0).getCustomer_id();
            String subID = subsscriptions.get(0).getSubscription_id();
            idDB.addCustomerID(cusID, subID);
        }
        Toast.makeText(AddSubscription.this, "SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Log.d("onresponse", "" + statusCode);
        finish(); <-- add this
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<SubModel>> call, Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(AddSubscription.this, "Network issues", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Log.d("onfailure"," " +  t . getMessage());
        finish(); <-- add this
    }
});
//finish(); <-- remove this
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. the customerID I need to pass to the fetchInfo method is not added but not retrieved when the activity resumes. it is only retrieved when i close and open the activity again. i have edited my question and added logcat.

Comment: I do not have enough reputations to add image yet so there is a link to my logcat

Comment: I have checked your attached image, its seems that you getting empty [] response because of `cus_id` is pass as blank in to API

Comment: exactly. but when i close recyclerview activity and open it again, i get customerID. i do not understand

Comment: i have tried it. it still does not wait to get the response.

Comment: please remove `finish();` after calling `activate.enqueue(...);` check my edited ADD activity code

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this I have just edited your code

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_subscriptions);

db = SubscriptionDB.getInstance(this);
sessionDBHelper = new SessionDBHelper(this);
idDB = IDsDB.getInstance(this);


FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.floatAddSub);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Subscriptions.this, AddSubscription.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});

customerID = idDB.getCustomerID();

progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
recyclerview = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.subscription_recycler);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
recyclerview.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
recyclerview.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

fetchInfo(customerID);

}

private void loadDataInRecyclerView(){
    //if you have already data loaded from API then why are you again loading data from db.getAll();
    //if this is not necessary try commenting it
    subArrayList = db.getAll();
    adapter = new SubRVAdapter(subArrayList, this, this.getSupportFragmentManager());
    recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void fetchInfo(String customerID) {
apiInterface = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(APIInterface.class);
Call<ArrayList<SubObject>> call = apiInterface.getSubscription(customerID);
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<SubObject>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<SubObject>> call, Response<ArrayList<SubObject>> response) {
        adapter = new SubRVAdapter(subArrayList, getApplicationContext(), getSupportFragmentManager());
        subArrayList = response.body();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        int statusCode = response.code();
        if(subArrayList.size()==0){
            Log.i("No data" , "Inside Response : " + "");
        }else{
            loadDataInRecyclerView();
        }

        Log.d("onresponse", "" + statusCode);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<SubObject>> call, Throwable t) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Log.d("onfailure", " " + t.getMessage());

        Toast.makeText(Subscriptions.this, "There is a network issue. Try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
});
}



@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();
Log.d("onResume", "RESUME");
fetchInfo(customerID);
if (subArrayList.size() > 0) {
    recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}}
```

Let me know if this works FYI I have done some editing in `onCreate()` method and your `fetchInfo()` method also pay attention to my comments in `fetchInfo()` method

Comment: Still doesn't work. the customerID I need to pass to the fetchInfo method is not added but not retrieved when the activity resumes. it is only retrieved when i close and open the activity again. i have edited my question and added logcat.

Comment: I do not have enough reputations to add image yet so there is a link to my logcat